# Formula issue Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I need help urgently for a work problem.

So basically, the summation of **opening stock** and **production** give **total stock**.
While closing stock is `((opening stock+production)-sale))` and stock cover is Closing stock/Sale.

I need help in creating a formula using excel to make sure my stock cover equates to 1.5 without manually inputting production. For example, I want a formula that determines production with values rounded up to the nearest 500 which result in a stock cover of 1.5.

Comment: What have you tried exactly?  You can calculate the summation by using *Sum* formula.

Comment: Theres already a summation. and unfortunately I cannot post the picture

Comment: Well, you could post all the equations, one at a line.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the cell reference for the names, so "Sales" below is the cell where this is, which might be something like A1, similarly "Open Stock" might be B1.

```
production = sales * 2.5 - opening stock
```

This does not fix the rounding up to the nearest 500. For that try

```
rounded_up_production = ROUNDUP(production/500,0)*500
```

And for the zero bounds

```
if(rounded_up_production<0,0,rounded_up_production)
```

Or combine them into one, fairly horrible formula

```
rounded_up_production = IF(ROUNDUP((sales * 2.5 - open stock)/500,0)*500<0,0,ROUNDUP((sales * 2.5 - open stock)/500,0)*500)
```